# Y-axis created but invisible

Tags: javascript, html, css, d3.js

I have create a simple barchart with `D3.js` with the following code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
    <title>Bar Transition Example</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>

 </head>
 <body>

<script type="text/javascript">

var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 60},
    width = 300 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 400 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var x = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .rangeRoundBands([0, width], .1);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([height, 0]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .orient("bottom");

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .orient("left")
    .ticks(5);

data = [{"label":"apples","value":6000},{"label":"pears","value":5000},{"label":"bananas","value":4000}]


function bars(data)
{

    x.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.label; }));
    y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.value; })]);

    d3.select("svg").append('g')
    .attr("class", "x axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(xAxis);

    d3.select("svg").append('g')
    .attr("class", "y axis")
    .call(yAxis)
    .append("text")
    .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
    .attr("y", 6)
    .attr("dy", ".90em")
    .style("text-anchor", "end");

   bars = d3.select("svg").selectAll(".bar")
    .data(data)

    //enter
    bars.enter().append("rect")
    .attr("class", "bar")
    .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.label); })
    .attr("width", x.rangeBand())
    .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.value); })
    .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.value); });

}


function init()
{

    //setup the svg
    var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

    bars(data)
}

init();
    </script>

 </body>
</html>
```

Yet my Y axis doesn't visualise as I would expect. Indeed,
 the Y axis is created
[image]

I tried tweaking all the parameters (including the margin variables

```
var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 60},
        width = 300 - margin.left - margin.right,
        height = 400 - margin.top - margin.bottom;
```

but with no effect.

Comment: You want to use the *variable* `svg` when appending your other elements, rather than using `d3.select('svg')` because your variable svg is actually a `<g>` element that has been shifted to sit within your margins. You could either define the variable outside of your init function, or give the `<g>` element inside it a class and select that when appending your other items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to translate the group that will contain the axis:

```
d3.select("svg").append('g')
    .attr('transform', 'translate(' + [margin.left, margin.top] + ')')
    .attr("class", "y axis")
    .call(yAxis);
```

The axis is being drawn outside the SVG element. You may want to translate the other group as well. Regards,

Comment: But then I also need to translate my `bars`

Comment: You will need to translate both axes and the bars. It's probably best if you create a group that will contain the bars, and translate the group instead.